Win32gui cant setWindowPos on tkinter window
I am trying to place a Tk window I created over another window (it's a heads up display) and everything is working except I cannot figure out how to keep the stack order of the window. It appears I cannot use win32gui to set the window position.
def Move(self):
    try:
        # size of the target window
        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.target_hwnd)
        x,y,w,h = rect[0], rect[1], rect[2]-rect[0], rect[3]-rect[1]

        # hwnd of our tk window
        window_id = self.root.winfo_id()

        # old working method used to place the TK window in the 
        # correct position and size
        # self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h, x,y))
        # self.bg.configure(width=300,height=100) 

         # places the tk window BELOW our target window
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(window_id, self.target_hwnd ,x, y, w, h, False)

        # places the target window BELOW our tk window
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(self.target_hwnd, window_id,x, y, w, h, False)
        
        # refresh this move function after 900 MS
        self.root.after(900, self.Move)
    except:
        # destroy the window if we cant find a window with the target HWND
        self.root.destroy()


The above code is what I am using to refresh the position and size and figured I would place a win32.setWindowPos() instead of using the tk geometry() since win32gui's 2nd parameter allows for a 2nd HWND to place the window below it on the stack/z-index. However, when ran it does not do anything (does not even position the window) so I wrote a test script to see if I can get the desired outcome with 2 normal windows
def move(hwnd1,hwnd2):
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd1)
    x,y,w,h = rect[0], rect[1], rect[2]-rect[0], rect[3]-rect[1]
    
    rect1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd2)
    x1,y1,w1,h1 = rect1[0], rect1[1], rect1[2]-rect1[0], rect1[3]-rect1[1]

    # places the window 2 BELOW window 1
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd1, hwnd2 ,x, y, w , h, False)
    
    # place window 1 BELOW window 2
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd2, hwnd1 ,x1, y1, w1, h1, False)

and this worked and gave me exactly what I was trying to do. Why can't I move a tk window with win32gui like I can a normal window?
Also, I was using the attribute -topmost on the root of my tk window and this works fine until another window overlays the target window but the tk window stays on top and is not my desired outcome. I need the window to keep the stack order of the other window.

you need to use the parent of window_id = self.root.winfo_id() if I recall correctly.

Yeah, that is what I am using with the first block of code. The second block does not have it because I used testing with 2 normal windows to see if it gives the desired results and it does. For some reason win32gui does not even move the window with the proper HWND

Why don't you simply use lift and lower on tkinter windows instead of these low level commands?
